# "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll" when inserting textbox values into SQL database

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, visual-studio

I am a complete noob to C# who is attempting to insert values that the user enters into various text boxes into a SQL database. Specifically, I am creating an account creation page. I am met with the above error when debugging and inserting values into the textbox/database.

Additional information includes

> Incorrect syntax near '@pword'.

If any additional information is needed, I am able to provide it.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-P3JSE1C;Initial Catalog=logins;Integrated Security=True");
        {

            SqlCommand ins = new SqlCommand("Insert into Users(userid, fullName, username, email, pword) Values(@userid, @fullName, @username, @email, @pword", connection) ;

            ins.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", textBox1.Text);
            ins.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fullName", textBox2.Text);
            ins.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", textBox3.Text);
            ins.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", textBox4.Text);
            ins.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pword", textBox5.Text);

            connection.Open();
            ins.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: missing closing parens after @pword

Comment: Aside from the missed closing parenthesis.  The userid column I am assuming is a primary key? If so, it should not be entered in a text box. It should be assigned by the system.